# how to delete all combobox in short codes

Tags: c#, combobox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVUTU.jpg)

I have 41 combobox and instead of coding each one of them combobox1.resettext(); bla bla how to make it short

Comment: Are those combobox all on the same container (the form ?)

Comment: Put them in a container control and use `var combos=container.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>(); foreach(ComboBox c in combos)cb.ResetText();`

Answer (score 2):

If all of your comboboxes are contained in the same container (mean that they are direct children of the form and not contained in a panel or groupbox) then you could use this code

```
foreach(ComboBox cbo in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
   cbo.ResetText();
```

The [IEnumerable OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) allows to iterate through the Controls collection of the form extracting only the elements of the specified type.

As explained in the comment below from Mr Schmelter this code loops on every combo present in the form Controls collection. If you have some combos that you don't want to reset then it is a good idea to move these combos in a separate container like a panel (with or without borders) so the code doesn't affect them

Comment: But it would be better to put them into a panel or groupbox since they seem to be related and you don't want to reset the text of unrelated comboxes.

Comment: That's true @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 0):

You can add all your combobox in an array and iterate through this array.

```
foreach(var combo in myCombos){
   combo.ResetText()
}
```

If all your combos are in a container you can get them by :

```
var myCombos=yourContainer.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>();
```